# Script for service management

Tags: bash, scripts

i need your support to create a script necessary to deploy, start and stop a service from one server to the others server.
This service is a jar with a properties file.

I would create a menu script with more choice.

I've created it like this:

> #!/bin/bash
> PS3='Please enter your choice: '
> options=("Start" "Stop" "Deploy" "Quit")
> select opt in "${options[@]}"
> do
> case $opt in
> "Start Shaw")
> echo "you chose choice 1"
> ;;
> "Stop Shaw")
> echo "you chose choice 2"
> ;;
> "Check Shaw Status")
> echo "you chose choice 3"
> ;;
> "Quit")
> break
> ;;
> *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
> esac
> done

i don't know how to connect the choices to the various functions.

Start function:

I thought of such a thing:

> function start_service ( )
> {
> ssh $1 'nohup /data/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -jar -Xmx1024M /data/apps/file.jar &'
> }
> echo "Starting servers"
> for serv_name in $( cat /data/server_list/list.txt )
> do
> start_service ${serv_name} &
> echo $! > pid.file &
> sleep 5
> done

where list.txt is a file with all the servers where this service need to be start.
The problem is that i need that the file pid.file is created on each server and that by launching it from the first server, a process is not created on the first server for each server listed but one process for each server.

Stop:

i need that starting from the pid.file, a command that read the file.pid and stop that process like:
kill $(cat pid.file)

Deploy:

this is the very problem.
I'd like to create a folder where putting the jar file or the properties file inside it, selecting this function, the file is deployed on all servers in the defined paths:
jar file: /pathtofile/apps/file.jar
file properties: /pathtofile/conf/file.properties

Comment: Looks like you are re-inventing a couple wheels. Starting/stopping services is something that systemd is already very good at. So you should be able to define the services for systemd, then simply ssh a systemd command instead of mucking about with nohup and pidfiles.

Comment: can i have an help with the start and stop function....the last request of deploy at the moment it is not necessary. I would receive an help to associate the menu choice with the different functions